# How can I delete the Index file in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, indexing, delete-file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

But when I'm in my page menu and click "home" I'm redirecting to www.page.com/index.

I want it to be like: www.page.com

Comment: Change the link on your menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can write rule for index.html file

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything :/